# Getting Text data from webpages by list of urls

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am extracting the text and some other info from webpage by using this script:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/anzeige.-digitalisierung-wie-software-die-kreativitaet-steigert-178413')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

and then just defined what i needed:

```
all = soup.select('.PageArticle')
title = []
author = []
publish_date = []
article_main_content = []
article_body = []
for item in all:
    t = item.find_all('h1')[0].text
    title.append(t)
    a = item.find_all('span')[2].text
    author.append(a)
    p = item.find_all('span')[5].text
    publish_date.append(p)
    amc = item.select('.PageArticle_lead-content')[0].text
    article_main_content.append(amc)
    a_body = item.select('.PageArticle_body')[0].text
    article_body.append(article_body)
```

and put them into df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":title, "Author": author, "Publish_date": publish_date,
                   "Article_Main_Content": article_main_content, "Article_Body": article_body })
```

I am having two problem:

**First Problem:** When i try to get the contents from the Article which consists of about 500-800 words. I am getting empty string.. Is there any limit problem?

This is my output:
[image]

is there any way to solve this?

**Second Problem:**

I have list of URL where i want to do same procedure and want to store all the info in same df.. How i can use list if urls for such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem**
You have a typo in the last line:

```py
    # Change this article_body.append(article_body)
    article_body.append(a_body)
```

**Second problem**
Loop over the list.

```
for url in url_list:
   # Your code
   r = requests.get(url)
   c = r.content
   soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
   print(soup.prettify())
   # The rest of your code...
```